# Comment Moderation Panel in wp-admin

Tags: wordpress

I need a modification Comment Moderation Panel in wp-admin

I want only zero approved comments posts in the pending section.

How can I do this? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove/accept all comments which are not approved yet, then go to AdminCP -> Comments. Click on "Pending (x)" and from there you may do whatever you want.

You can also go to this link (need to modify with your base URL): http://[BASEURL]/wp-admin/edit-comments.php?comment_status=moderated

If that's not what you wanted, please give more information as I'm not quite sure about your problem.

Comment: Yes I know the url. I want only this.

If I have previously approved a comment in a post.

I do not want to see the post "/edit-comments.php?comment_status=moderated" in this link.

only to be zero comments posts in the link.